# Add a dropdown list to the moderator convert-to-comment tool

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

I like very much the recently-added ability to convert an answer to a comment. However, the dialog requires the actual ID of the post that will be the parent. It auto-fills the question ID, but for an answer, I have to go hover over the "link" button and memorize the ID (or else copy the whole link and delete everything but the ID).

Here's a screenshot so you don't have to read that terribly long paragraph to see what I mean:

[image: convert to comment]

The list should ideally show a) the author, b) the first bit of the answer, and c) as a tiebreaker (if necessary) the answer ID.

Comment: How would you identify the answer in the list? First couple dozen characters and the author's name? Instead of a dropdown, perhaps the better solution is one you alluded to - make it accept a link as well as the ID directly, like closing as a duplicate does.

Comment: @Kyle: thanks, forgot that bit.

Comment: Good idea.  I usually follow the link and copy the PostID out of the address bar.  It would be much easier if the authors were listed in a drop-down.

Comment: The glaring Internet Explorer CSS Rendering is killing my eyes!

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: Where? What's unusual here?

Comment: @mmyers [New hotness](http://i.imgur.com/L7tc7.png) Though this is on a different site. Maybe meta really has square close links.

Comment: @Marco: I think mmyers drew that drop-down freehand.  ;)  (Seriously though, that's how the buttons look in FF on SO.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard On the contrary the drop-down is awesome! I was commenting on the square close button. But I appear to be wrong that it's not just IE :P

Comment: That field already accepts a link; that's what I've always used

Comment: ^ last comment just saved me a huge headache. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Using @MichaelMrozek's comment from the above.

I've found success in clicking "share" on an answer to get the URL and pasting it into the target box. Saved me a huge headache when a new member asked a follow up question to a posted answer... as another answer >_<

A dropdown of all available answers and the question would certainly be a positive improvement.