# Improve Convert-Answer-to-Comment dialog to list answers as possible targets

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderation, convert-to-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a dropdown list to the moderator convert-to-comment tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77975/add-a-dropdown-list-to-the-moderator-convert-to-comment-tool)

[Moderators are able to convert answers to comments below the question or other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments).

The current dialog allows the moderator to provide the target post of the to-be-created comment:

[image: Existing Dialog]

The dialog is preset with the ID of the question but moderators have to manually copy and paste the ID of or a link to the answer they want to receive the comment. This is **not very user-friendly**! The dialog should include a list of all answers, e.g. as a drop-down list. The format could be `12345 - Answer of Username` like for the question.
This shouldn't be very difficult to implement and be a nice improvement of the moderator interface.

Comment: Is this that much different from [this similar dropdown list request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77975/add-a-dropdown-list-to-the-moderator-convert-to-comment-tool)?

Comment: @Grace: No, it seems to be a duplicate. Sorry, I was searching for an existing request beforehand but didn't found that one.

Comment: No worries. The fact you posted a duplicate for this, among other things, just indicates how universal our request for the dropdown it. ♪

Comment: Dunno, I actually never have an issue with this process (and I'm a sticker for little annoyances in the UI that add up over time).  Almost all the time I can see the link of the target post within the screen, so I can drag the link into the text box and roll.  And, if you didn't know, you don't have to clear the text box before adding a different URL to it; the controller is smart enough to strip off the default text when evaluating the post.