# Mod -> Convert to comment, in addition to question, give me quick-fix for "accepted answer"

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment

Most of the time, answers that are really comments either apply to the question (like "I have this problem too, did you manage to fix it?") or to the accepted answer ("thanks! that fixed it!").

Could we get a quick-selection for the accepted answer as well as the question?

Right now, when I click the "Convert to comment" mod command, it shows a textbox defaulting to the question. Now I have to go grab the link to the accepted answer and paste that in there instead, and I see almost as many "Thanks" answers as "Me too" answers.

Pretty please? :)

---

Ok, the above text was too terse I'll admit.

What I mean by the "Thanks" and "Me too" comments, the ones I want to move are the more detailed ones, like the one I commented on Jeff's answer below, like "Thanks, that nearly solved it, but I still have a problem with doohickey X, do you know how to fix that as well?" or similar.

In my opinion, the OP probably shouldn't accept the answer at that point, since the chance of getting more complete answers sinks drastically if there is an accepted answer to the question, but users do what users do.

Comment: Shouldn't these be deleted anyway?

Comment: LOL people actually accept such answers? Do you have a link?

Comment: People sometimes accept answers if it remotely looks like it might answer their question, even before they try it and find that it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Would it be crazy to just list all the possible targets, instead of taking a freeform string?
[image: Mockup]

The odds of picking the wrong post are low, and if the mod does make it mistake it's simple to fix (barring certain [issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94627/converting-to-comment-multiple-times-leaves-behind-undelete-votes)). The close dialog has a bulleted list, while the mod migration dialog has a dynamic search field; either of those seem better than just a plain textbox. Now that I think about it, I kind of like the dynamic search option, since it lets people search by ID, URL, post text, author display name, or whatever else it wants to support, and it's backwards-compatible with the current implementation

Comment: Yes, that would be nice, better than just listing question + accepted answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is all that necessary, because from my experience in comment conversion, I don't see the accepted answer getting a *significantly* higher attention than any other answer target. This lack of frequency tends to be more visible when the comment-as-answer comes from someone other than the author of the question. I see these usually come before an answer has been accepted, or other times it's a rebuttal/clarification request to an answer someone has posted.

I've largely not noticed this especially happening in the direction of accepted answers, so I don't think the accepted answer needs any particular special attention over all of the other answers. I'd much prefer that we just get [some kind of general quick select for all of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77975/add-a-dropdown-list-to-the-moderator-convert-to-comment-tool) over just the accepted answer. Maybe prioritize the accepted answer to the top of said listing, as such a priority wouldn't cause a large impact on the cases where it isn't the accepted answer as the target.

Answer (score 2):

If you literally mean 'answers' like

> thanks! that fixed it!

These should *not* be converted to comments. (I usually proxy upvote the post they are referring to in this case.)

These comments should be **deleted** unless they substantively, constructively add to the post in some way.

Comment: No, I generally mean more detailed answers, it was a short example, but I see your point. Examples are more like "Thanks, that nearly solved it, but I still have a problem with doohickey X that you didn't mention, do you know how to solve this as well?"